# Table ordering with a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I am trying to populate my table, i am calling my api and doing the following

```
const addressTd = addressesInfo.map(item => (
<TableRow>
  <TableCell align="right">{item.officeName}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{item.address1}</TableCell>
</TableRow>));
```

then within my return I do the following

```
 <Table>
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>Office Name</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Address Line 1</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      <TableCell>{addressTd}</TableCell>
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
```

however this does not give the desired affect
[image]

How could i allow office street to actually render under address? Thankyou

Comment: I don't think you need to wrap your `{adressTd}` in `<TableCell>`, you're already returning rows and cells from your .map

Comment: @sanjsanj you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually rendering all rows inside a cell. Here's the fixed version:

```
const addressTrs = addressesInfo.map((item, i) => 
  <TableRow key={i}>
    <TableCell align="right">{item.officeName}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="right">{item.address1}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>
);

<Table>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell>Office Name</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Address Line 1</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {addressTrs}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Also it's mandatory to have an unique `key` if you have an array of elements.